# How to pass string as argument for QTextEdit signal

Tags: qt, qt5

Is it possible to pass string as an argument for `QTextEdit`?

This is how I am trying to implement it currently.

```
QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit;
QObject::connect(textEdit, &QTextEdit::textChanged, this, &ParamChangeText);

void ParamChangeText(QString qstr)
{
    qDebug() << qstr;
}
```

But I get the error that signal and slot are not compatible.

Comment: `QTextEdit::textChanged()` signal has no parameters. It cannot be connected to a slot with parameters.

Comment: @vahancho does QTextEdit has any signal where i can pass the string.

Comment: No, AFAIK, but you don't need such a signal. In your slot (without parameters) you can read the current text directly from your text edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three quick ways to achieve this:

1. You know that such slot is invoked only when that specific `QTextEdit`(`textEdit`) changes, and the slot have access to that variable. In this case just use `textEdit->toPlainText()` (or HTML or Markdown variants) to retrieve the string.
2. The slot is in a different object with no access to `textEdit` or there may be several `QTextEdit` connected to the same slot. In Qt, when a slot is invoked from a signal, [`QObject::sender()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) returns the object that emitted the signal. You can simply cast it to get the `QTextEdit`:

```
void ParamChangeText()
{
    auto textEdit = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(sender());
    if (textEdit) { // will be null if sender() doesn't return a QTextEdit
        qDebug() << textEdit->toPlainText();
    }
}
```

3. Finally, you may use Qt 5 new signal / slot syntax and use a lambda function to do the work, at expenses of an extra function call. Be careful that `sender()` doesn't return the emitter object on lambdas, but you can solve it by capturing the `QTextEdit`:

```
// Omit textEdit from capture list if it is a member of class
QObject::connect(textEdit, &QTextEdit::textChanged, [this, textEdit]() {
  ParamChangeText(textEdit->toPlainText());
});

void ParamChangeText(QString qstr)
{
    qDebug() << qstr;
}
```